# exception happened when setting UIPanGestureRecognizer delegate

Tags: ios, exception, delegates, scrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

I need to detect the length of horizontal scroll and do something

```
 UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer;     
 panGestureRecognizer=[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:)];
```

at the same time allowing user to scroll vertically as normal.
So I set UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, but exception happens.

```
 MyGestureDelegate *deleg = [[MyGestureDelegate alloc] init];
 [panGestureRecognizer setDelegate:deleg];
 [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
```

Here's my delegate.m

```
@interface MyGestureDelegate : NSObject <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@end

@implementation MyGestureDelegate

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
return YES;
}
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
return YES;
}
```

what can I do to make it right?

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: Wow, actually `UIScrollView` already contains it's own  `UIPanGestureRecognizer ` by default. Maybe I didn't understand you right, but if you want to know how much user drags the content on your scroll it is definitely possible to get by means of   `UIScrollView` ' s property -`contentOffset`.